# aws iam user access denied despite full permission

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have created an IAM user and associate the user with a group. For the group i have assigned AWSS3FullAccess policy but still when I login to the aws console as IAM user and click on S3, I see only access denied. 
Pasted below:

[image]

I am able to view the buckets from admin user as below:
[image]

Here's my policy:
[image]
Couldnt find any related thread related to this. How does one debug such issues?

Comment: Please edit your question to expand on what you mean by "when I login to the aws console as IAM user I see only access denied". For example, what did you do to get the error message? Does it work for other buckets?

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, Have added some details and screenshot

Comment: The screenshot definitely suggests that you do not have Amazon S3 permissions, or the buckets have been setup with very locked-down bucket policies. Can the root user (login via email address) see the buckets? Can any other IAM users see the buckets?

Comment: @JohnRotensteinyes the admin can see the buckets and create new ones but not the IAM user. Added screenshots for reference

Comment: Who are you logged in as when you _can_ see the buckets? As the root user (via email address), or as an IAM User with Admin permissions?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein root user with admin rights

Comment: It would appear that the IAM User does not have the permissions you assigned. You could experiment by creating a new user and assigning them the `AdministratorAccess` permission. That should work. If so, remove that and then assign `AWSS3FullAccess`. Somehow, something is not configured as you expect.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes creating a new user with admin access and then scaling down to S3 full access works for the new user. but the current user is still showing access denied. Is it safe to assume that specific user is corrupted or something? How do you debug these as an admin?

Comment: There is probably something else that you have not noticed that is causing the difference. I would recommend deleting the "non-working" user and recreating, and it will probably work just fine. Or, maybe they aren't in the group, or perhaps there are other policies in the group that are interfering.

Comment: Yes, deleting and recreating worked. Weird issues, wish i had some logging/way to debug. Thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple inputs from [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein), it looks like the user was corrupted with some other policy/group setings. Deleting the user and re-creating worked fine.